# Batch creation of shortened URLs with Goo.gl

Tags: goo.gl

I would like to create 20-30 shortened URLs to Google Documents using Google own URL shortener Goo.gl. Does anybody know if this is possible or do I need to enter them one by one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my thoughts :

1. use the goo.gl url shortener API
2. write code to loop through all the links and shorten them.
3. get short links

*want me to write the code?*

Comment: Thanks. Don't need to write the code (at least not for me). I used a simpler way and don't need all those links. T

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative: using a Chrome extension like "[goo.gl URL Shortener](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/googl-url-shortener/iblijlcdoidgdpfknkckljiocdbnlagk/related?hl=en-US)" to automatize the process of URL shortening.

I will stick to this solution.